# C++ slicing caused by reference

Tags: c++, stl, pass-by-reference

I have problem to understand the behavior of the following code, which I modified from an example for C++ slicing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

struct B { 
    int x; 
    B() { x = 0; } 
    virtual void foo( const char* id ) { 
        std::cout << id << ": B="  << this << ", x=" << x << std::endl; 
    } 
};

struct D1 : B  { 
    int y;
    D1() { x = 1; y = 100; } 
    virtual void foo( const char* id ) { 
        std::cout << id << ": D1=" << this << ", x=" << x << ", y=" << y << std::endl; 
    } 
} d1;

struct D2 : B  {
    int z;
    D2() { x = 2; z = 200; } 
    virtual void foo( const char* id ) { 
        std::cout << id << ": D2=" << this << ", x=" << x << ", z=" << z  << std::endl; 
    } 
} d2;

void main() {
    std::cout << "d1 = " << &d1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "d2 = " << &d2 << std::endl;

    std::cout << "By pointer at beginning: " << std::endl;
    B* pb = &d1;
    pb->foo( "pd1" );
    pb = &d2;
    pb->foo( "pd2" );

    std::cout << "By Value: " << std::endl;
    B b = d1;
    b.foo( "d1" );
    b = d2;
    b.foo( "d2" );

    std::cout << "By pointer after by value: " << std::endl;
    pb = &d1;
    pb->foo( "pd1" );
    pb = &d2;
    pb->foo( "pd2" );

    std::cout << "By reference: " << std::endl;
    B& rb = d1;
    rb.foo( "rd1" );
    rb = d2;
    rb.foo( "rd2" );

    std::cout << "By pointer after by reference: " << std::endl;
    pb = &d1;
    pb->foo( "pd1" );
    pb = &d2;
    pb->foo( "pd2" );
}

//The result is the following:
d1 = 0115B504
d2 = 0115B510
By pointer at beginning:
pd1: D1=0115B504, x=1, y=100
pd2: D2=0115B510, x=2, z=200
By Value:
d1: B=0036FE44, x=1
d2: B=0036FE44, x=2
By pointer after by value:
pd1: D1=0115B504, x=1, y=100
pd2: D2=0115B510, x=2, z=200
By reference:
rd1: D1=0115B504, x=1, y=100
rd2: D1=0115B504, x=2, y=100
By pointer after by reference:
pd1: D1=0115B504, x=2, y=100
pd2: D2=0115B510, x=2, z=200
```

From the above result, we can see that:

- Value assignment causes slicing problem to the assign destination (b) by dropping the derived specific members, but leave the assign sources (d1 and d2) intact.
- Reference assignment causes slicing to the assign destination (rd) by not assigning the derived specific members, thus partially changes the assign sources (d1 and d2).

At first, I was surprised that you can assign a reference to a different type (D2 to D1) via their base, until I realize the infamous C++ casting system. One conclusion seems that reference can only be initialized but not assigned.

We know that STL container for base object has slice problem because except list, all other STL container copy object around.  It looks that STL container for base references should fair no better, unless it saves pointers inside.

How do you guys deal with this problem?

Thanks!
CP

Comment: "One conclusion seems that reference can only be initialized but not assigned." - Yes, that is true.  A reference is an **alias** to the original object.

Comment: "At first, I was surprised that you can assign a reference to a different type (D2 to D1) via their base, until I realize the infamous C++ casting system."

You can't. That's not what happened. You assigned d2 to the object referenced by b.

If you had walked thru this with the debugger you'd more likely have seen the copy and understood what was going on.

Comment: "_until I realize the infamous C++ casting system_" Nope. There is no casting here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm finding it hard to find a question in your text, but I'm going to assume it is something like:

> "How do I polymorphically store objects in a standard container?"

First, let me just say that you can't store references in standard containers because you can't assign (rebind) them.

So the normal way is to have a container of base class pointers. If the container owns the items, then use smart pointers like `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`. If the container does not own the objects, then just use raw pointers.

Comment: I think that in C+11 you can find way to store reference in container.

Answer (score 1):

```
B& rb = d1;
rb.foo( "rd1" );
rb = d2;
```

The last line is equivalent as if you wrote

```
d1 = d2;
```

except it applies only to base class subobject. In the first line you set up the reference creating `rb` as alias to `d1` with different static type. The reference can not be reseated. The later assign targets the object. d1 directly could only be assigned with using trickery with its op=, but your changed static type makes Base::op= work.

Many mentors say you should only use abstract classes as base, and most of the reasoning points to accidents like this.

In hierarchies you rarely have the op= left, if absolutely needed you have some virtual ssign thing that verifies compatibility.

Comment: The problem here is that the `Base::operator=` is not virtual. If it was virtual, then it will call the assignment operator in the derived class.

Comment: @newacct Making `Base::operator=` virtual would not in itself be sufficient. You would also need to override it in the derived class. And then, what would you do in `Derived1::operator=` with a `Derived2`?

Comment: I had a hierarchy with support for assignment, I used a function called AssignVirt(const Base&) to avoid confusion. It was implemented by the common macro along with Clone, Create and others. Implementation used made sure the rhs  was same type as *this and applied the stock op=. It allowed a lot of common polymorphic code, while each client normally dealt with just a single concrete type.

Comment: @BalogPal What if the type of rhs did not match the type of lhs?

Comment: in my case there was an assert and no operation, as I considered proper match a precondition. For other cases throwing exception seem fair, or just do nothing.